Potentially viable methods of accelerating a projectile of 10kg to relativistic speed within the limitations and requirements below
Is there a potentially workable method of accelerating a 10kg projectile to relativistic speed (in this question it is defined as 1%C even though the lorenz factor is fairly small at this speed) within the limitations and setting provided below?
1: energy is in abundance, the energy requirement of any proposal could be fufilled so long as it is below 4.0x10^26 joules
2: the object's exact geometry and composition is irrelavent so long as it is still a solid by the time the launching mechanism have ceased interaction with it (for example in a coilgun it is when the projectile left the barrel, in laser ablative it's when the laser beam is turned off)
3: the projectile do not have to carry anything with it (no passenger, electronics etc) unless it is a part of the launching mechanism, only it's own mass. extremely high G is acceptable
4: the solution should only use physically possible mechanisms (aka not handwavium), however within this boundary it is acceptable to use hard to obtain methods and materials
5: not strictly necessary, but it is preferable if the launch can be completed within one AU or less, so high acceleration is a desirable feature

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

0.01c is relativistic? That's like the USAF giving astronaut merit badges to people who've flown above 80 km. I mean, its an achievement, but it is hardly the real thing.
Anyway, one percent of c is relatively achievable. You probably don't want to do it with a coilgun, because keeping everything nicely aligned over the entire acceleration length (which will necessarily be Quite Long) is a difficult bit of engineering.
You might be able to do it via laser-ablative propulsion, but I'm finding sources to be lacking here. From Review: Laser-Ablation Propulsion, I can see that generating relativistic ion beams (and hence providing relativistic exhaust velocities, which is what you need for propulsion) from ultrashort laser pulses is very much possible, but I'm finding little information about possible thrust levels, or power efficiency (which seems likely to be punishingly low).
Instead, I'll break out my old favorite, Jordin Kare's Sailbeam. The basic idea here is that you have a propelled object that carries a magnetic pusher plate of some kind, such as a magnetic sail, a suitable power source, and a relatively small amount of propellant gas or some kind of small laser. You then have a much more substantial fixed laser which drives a large number of small lightsails which mass perhaps 10-20 milligrams each and are made out of very thin refractory materials such as CVD diamond, formed into a dielectric mirror tuned for maximum reflectivity at the drive laser's wavelength and maximum transparency at other wavelengths. The launching laser can drive these tiny sails with significant accelerations, and it doesn't need to be capable of the fancy ultrashort pulses that an ablator needs, which reduceds the engineering requirements somewhat. As they reach the target, it either puffs out a little bit of gas which the sail collides with, or strobes its laser at a wavelength the microsail strong absorbs, or the sail otherwise self destructs to produce a cloud of plasma that is deflected by the magentic sail to provide thrust.
Kare talks of using this to drive probes to 0.1c or faster, so clearly the technique should be capable of doing everything you need and more. He does also speak of laser ablation perhaps being better at ~0.01 to 0.02 c, but unhelpfully doesn't back that up with references.

later addition
For something a bit more particle beam based, as you've said you'd like, consider PROCSIMA: Diffractionless Beamed Propulsion for
Breakthrough Interstellar Missions. This is a newer idea than sailbeams, and uses a neat trick that makes use of the interaction of a laser beam with a particle beam to improve confinement and focussing of both.
This lets you get all the advantages of using a particle beam to drive something (eg. much higher power-to-thrust ratio compared to photons, potentially much higher emitter efficiency) but without all the problems associated with thermal and electromagnetic effects causing beam divergence and so strongly limiting your range. This is very similar in intent to sailbeams (hit your spaceship with matter to impart momentum to it! bounce stuff off a magnetic sail!) but significantly reduces the size of the laser bit.
The downside is that the math is somewhat harder, and so I leave it as an exercise for the reader. The 100 GW example system seems entirely capable of driving a multi-kilo payload to 0.01c. The acceleration time and distance are awkward to compute, but it looks like the payload should hit cruising speed within perhaps 10 million km (0.07 AU) of the launcher, so well within your 1 AU limit.

about the laser-ablative propulsion I think that I'm rather confident that it will not work without a astronomical mass ratio. the highest estimate for laser thermal performance suggest that it can achieve a specific impulse of 40,000m

@General_Ripper the linked paper gives emitted ion velocities in the multiple-MeV range. Relativistic laser ablative propulsion is potentially possible, but most research appears to be on much lower-velocity, higher-thrust stuff that is of more practical near-term use.

right now that I went to do some actual number crunching it turns out that I'm over conservative with the visual estimate, 40000m/s of exhaust velocity (previously I wrote specific impulse due to carelessness) actually means that according to the rocket equation I can reach my requirements with merely a mass ratio of 4 https://projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist.php#laserthermal

@General_Ripper I think you've definitely got your mass ratio wrong there. exp(0.01c / 40km/s) gives a ratio more like 3.5x10^32. When your exhaust velocity equals your delta-V, you get a mass ratio of e, and 40km/s is a long way from 2000 km/s.

good point...went back to check my calculator and noticed that there's a typo in the value I entered, should have payed attention in math class) Anyways, further question on the sailbeam. You mentioned that one of the potential mechanisms is for the lightsail drones to self destruct into plasma, can it work with a particle beam as well?

This seems like a good idea as far as I can tell. Main question I have is how they expect to keep the laser focused over such a long distance during the acceleration of the little mirrors. Lasers spread out and you would need a huge aperture laser with extremely high beam quality to maintain focus on the tiny mirror. If the beam quality is off a little bit, the mirror gets hit with the wrong frequency and melts. AFAIK I don't think we have any way to make huge-aperture lasers with extremely high beam quality.

I think there may be an error in his diagram on page 3. He shows the beam converging from the lens onto the microsail, but AFAIK beam convergence is not possible unless the lens is very far from the laser, something like half the distance between the laser and the microsail. Which would not be practical, especially since the required position of the lens would rapidly change as the microsail accelerates.

@General_Ripper particle beam used for what? propelling the target, propelling the microsails, or destroying the microsails?

@causative I think you're reading too much into some powerpoint art. I suspect it is only trying to convey the notion that the microsails are small (<1m diameter vs >10km for "conventional" lightsail).

@StarfishPrime Well, the problem of focusing the beam on a very small target very far away is an essential one and I do not believe it can be overcome as shown in the diagram. You need a laser that has a huge aperture coming straight off the lasing medium, so that you start with a very wide, coherent beam before you focus it anywhere. And that's incredibly hard to make.

@StarfishPrime I was thinking about propelling both the target as an initial boost, and the microsails. In my setting there happens to be very powerful particle beams but not a lot of powerful lasers

@StarfishPrime Actually, I think I'm wrong about that. I think the diagram on page 3 could work as shown, with the lens near the laser.

@General_Ripper well, if only you'd mentioned that before ;-) I have just the thing for you, but I'm off out now so you'll have to wait to find out what it is.

In fact I don't buy this idea in part of precision. The idea says you want precision controllers on microsails, but they are accelerated at millions of Gs, any electronics will be diffused into a single magical slab incapable of performing anything meaningful. I also dont see where does the microsail gain delta-V to adjust its course into the actual payload to transfer momentum. And aiming the entire sail beam requires precision beyond capability of any actuators. Also if there would be a single defect in aiming structure, cause by a single particle, its aim will be off the target right away.

Precision at cosmic lengths is an extremely complicated issue, more so than energy transfer even, as you could just gather solar power into rechargeable devices. So IMHO anything that's not rigid and requires distance of more than 1e4 km to do its job is unfeasible. Thus indeed, coilguns are off, but this thing is also off as its projectiles don't have a delta-V, also should they start hitting an edge of target, it will topple over and get subsequently blasted into plasma.

@Vesper "I personally can't imagine how you could make it with current technology therefore it is impossible"

Nuclear potato cannon on an asteroid
As it's currently standing, the lid over Plumbbob nuclear test is deemed to become the fastest moving object after the nuke went off, however due to Earth having atmosphere it was expected to vaporize from collisions with air molecules. But with the energy budget of 1e26 J it's feasible to build and then execute a similar blast off say Ceres, which does not have atmosphere to block the blast (or for extra kicks, Mercury, due to local abundance of solar power to probably accelerate the thing further). Either celestial body is big enough to not break apart from the nuke going off in their crust at depths of ~10-20 km, and is also dense enough to not burst open the shaft prior to it giving enough acceleration to the lid closing it, or an object located somewhere within, not too close to be turned into plasma and not too far away to actually benefit from The Kick of all the plasma created by subsurface nuclear explosion.
Of course, as nuclear explosion involves a ton of ablation on top of sheer penetrating radiation, the lid in this experiment should be rather complex. It should be separated into at least 4 parts: the compartment for the projectile, the compressor for it to not get splattered out by acceleration, the part that ablates while accelerating the above structure, and the connector structure that would also act as something that won't let the projectile collide with the shaft's walls. I would like to call this thing "ordnance" as it resembles a shot in the cannon chamber, with explosive part being the nuke.
However, the nuke to accelerate a something to 0.01c should be very large; given the recent calculation of a 2GT nuke going off close to a ship, it doesn't provide the necessary kick at such distance, but it could provide such a kick if blown point blank - the main issue would be to not turn the particle being accelerated into plasma. Also, since we decide to blow the nuke in a place surrounded by matter, we need to have the nuclear plasma be hot enough to reach particle velocity of no less than 0.01c when it will escape up the shaft and collide with our ordnance, since you cannot accelerate something by collision beyond the speed of colliding matter. This corresponds to no less than 3e10 degrees C for hydrogen-based plasma (Ceres has enough water in its crust for the plasma to have enough hydrogen), at this temperature the mean velocity of protons would be averaging 0.01c.
I'm not very aware of the exact physics of nuke vaporizing matter around it, as in how big would be the area of effect, how hot will be the plasma at t=0 and afterwards, how fast will be the neutrons released by the third stage fission, whether they alone would suffice to provide enough impulse to the structure etc, this process is expected to be researched by models only and likely have its results classified, but I think I can do some ballpark calculations based on Tsar Bomba's fission effectiveness projected into a water-filled chamber, ignoring minor scale effects like heating the water prior to it being vaporized or breaking the H-O bonds while ionizing either atom.
Assuming a 2GT nuke, and its fission effectiveness of 99.7%, also assuming that all the fission happened before the initial shockwave reached the ordnance, we have the total plasma energy of 8.3e18 J distributed over some space filled with plasma. We need this space to be small enough so at least some of its particles would reach 0.01c speed from temperature. This amount of energy is enough to accelerate to 0.01c 8.3e18/(3e6^2/2)/1.67e-27 particles of hydrogen, if all the energy would be absorbed into heat, this amounts to 1.1e33, or 1.84e6 kg of hydrogen. Say the volume initially was all water (the best case), it will then have 2/3 H and 1/3 O particles, so this energy would be enough to accelerate 6 times less mass of water ((1+1+1)/(1+1+16) where the divisor is sum of masses in H), or 307.4 tons, or 335 m^3 of water ice, aka a ball of 8.7m in diameter - sadly, a little bigger than the size of the bomb. But it's if all the mass would be accelerated to 0.01c, also since we can accelerate a sizable chunk of water to the required speed, 2GT nuke is theoretically possible to act as a potato cannon blower to give the required acceleration to the ordnance. Also this does not calculate the ablation effect on the ordnance, which uses its own mass to propel the particle faster than the cannon would push it initially. In case the outermost 1cm of matter would get heated by incoming radiation to  say 3e8 degrees C, it would leave the surface giving it extra unaccounted-for momentum. One can calculate the dimensions of the ordnance so that most of it would turn into plasma, which, together with the initial push of energized H+O particles, would be enough to accelerate the remainder to 0.01c. Yet... this requires testing, at least as a calculation model.
There's one other thing to check prior to trying to spend 1e26 J on such an effort, that is, whether the acceleration applied to the particle would not destroy its integrity. If the shaft is 10 km long from surface to where the ordnance is located, and the muzzle velocity is 0.009c (the rest is achieved by subsequent ablation of superheated parts of ordnance), the acceleration the particle has to suffer would at least be (0.009c)^2/(2*10 km) or 3,645e8 m/s^2, or 3.65 mega-Gs. I have failed to find how large an acceleration could a steel brick withstand without breaking, the largest cannon ever fired Schwerer Gustav (aka "Dora") only gives a mere 1000G kick to its shell, calculated from muzzle velocity and barrel length, so it's quite probable that despite all the precautions the particle would get splattered by acceleration. But it's perhaps the most feasible way of accelerating something to this velocity without calling some very extensive engineering or very serious energy losses (ablation acceleration from several AUs? Ha ha).

while starfish prime's answer does seem more plausible, the plumbbob cannon definitely sounds very cinematic) Would the projectile benefit from being made of stuff like tungsten to better withstand the nuke? or have a layer of liquid hydrogen to act as ablative propellant?

@General_Ripper not sure about tungsten, I'd choose titanium instead, the projectile itself should not get heated too hard if the ordnance is correctly built. Ablative propellant is accounted for, although I don't know which material would act best as such. IMHO beryllium would do better than hydrogen here, as it's also a neutron flux trap, and could also release additional energy from fusion, adding to total velocity of the projectile.

I can't imagine transferring that much energy into an object in one blip with enough efficiency to not melt it.  You have 4.5GJ/kg.  If I'm reading Wikipedia right the best material is carbon at 715Kj/mol = 59MJ/kg.  0.2% of the acceleration energy will vaporize your material and if you want it to actually survive you'll need to do far better than that.  (Tungsten is actually not good--high energy per mol but this is about energy per kg which strongly favors the light elements.

@LorenPechtel well that source of SailBeam in the other answer states that those "mini-sails" undergo comparable (to an order of magnitude) acceleration rates. So if those sails won't break apart (and they are frikking film of <1mcm thickness), why should this break apart or melt? If those microsails would break apart, then that whole idea is broken as well.

You could use nested coilguns. The first could get to 1%c, then shoot the second which could get to 2%, which could tben shoot its coilgun and fire the third mechanism, etc up to close to c.

At that point why not just make it one large coilgun, instead of having to shoot dozens of coilguns out of each one?

In the limit of breaking coilgun propulsion down into smaller and more efficient parts, you end up with essentially an ion thruster.

Tsiolkovsky will have very bad things to say about this approach.
